Listener for Internet Connection Ionic/Angular
Hey I am trying to add a listener to my ionic app that listens for change in network activity and then act accordingly.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@capacitor/network';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.initializeNetworkEvents();
  }

  initializeNetworkEvents() {
    Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', (status) => {
      console.log('Network status changed', status);
      
      if (status.connected) {
        this.syncOfflineData();
      }
    });

    // Check the current network status on app start
    this.checkNetworkStatus();
  }

  async checkNetworkStatus() {
    const status = await Network.getStatus();
    console.log('Current network status:', status);
  }

  async syncOfflineData() {
    console.log('Syncing offline data');
  }
}


Right now this is the code I have in my app.component.ts. It logs the status at start up but whenever I disconnect the wifi from my pc and connect it again it doesn't pick it up or log anything. Is it because I am using pc to test this out instead of mobile?

It should work in browser too. Did you maybe disconnect/connect the net too fast?

@MishaMashina I have figured it out, I was running it on localhost that's why lol. Tried it with offline Mode on chrome and it worked!

So I found the problem and just wanted to leave the answer here incase anyone got the same issue. Turns out I was in localhost that's why it wasn't working. I used offline Mode in chrome and it worked fine!
